# Let $G$ a finite group with order of $2p$, where $p > 2$ is prime. given that there's $a \in Z(G)$ such that $o(a) = 2$. Prove: $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Homework question:

> Let $G$ a finite group with order of $2p$, where $p > 2$ is prime. given that there's $a \in Z(G)$ such that $o(a) = 2$. Prove: $G$ is abelian.

Can you give me some hints and help to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: What will the order of $G/\langle a\rangle$ be?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: by Cauchy's theorem there is an element $x$ of order $p$. What does the subgroup generated by $a$ and $x$ look like, and what is its order?

Comment: Ahh, even simpler than my version. Though Cauchy is not needed, just that there is an element not of order $2$ (and if they are all of order $2$, then the group being abelian is a standard exercise).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft true, but you still need Lagrange's theorem with that argument.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Also your hint is a standard exercise, and that's the way I would have solved it. I agree this hints is very nice, and too bad only one wrote an answer as I would have upvoted both.

Comment: Sure, but Lagrange is generally covered earlier than Cauchy.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so the idea is to make the G = { $x^i$, $a*x^i$ } for $0 \le i<p$ ?

Comment: @Billie yes that's right.